# angular bootstrap popover - remove title in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wrote a small directive that show popover ([Angular-UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)) when the length of the text is to long.
Every time the popover been shown, it's always adds a blank row for title - how do i remove it?
when i'm doing it with `element.next().find('.popover-title').hide();` it places the popover in wrong position (17px above the object).

```
app.directive("descriptionPopover", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attributes) {

        element.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
            var msg = element.text();
            var maxWidth = attributes.widthPopover || 80;

            if (msg.length >= maxWidth ) {
                element.popover('destroy'); //refreshing the content from first init
                var pop = element.popover({
                    content: msg,
                    placement: "top",
                    trigger: "manual",
                    container: "body"
                });
                element.popover('show');
            }
        })
        .bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
            element.popover('hide');
        });

     };
});
```

[image]

any ideas?
Eddie

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem with a plunker or a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always edit popover template. You would need to use `ui-bootstrap.js` without bundled templates and download default ones from [project page](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)